# How can i connect Azure Active Directory (WAAD) to Windows Azure Access Control Service (ACS)?

Tags: azure, active-directory, acs, adfs, azure-active-directory

I am already using ACS and would love to setup Azure Active Directory as an identity provider.

I cant seem to find any way of getting ADFS info from WAAD but i guess its still early days...

Does anyone know if this is possible yet?

Joe

Answer (score 5):

Yes this is possible, have a look here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2012/11/07/provisioning-a-directory-tenant-as-an-identity-provider-in-an-acs-namespace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to connect the Windows Azure Active Directory through Access Control Service (ACS). This is basic feature of Windows Azure AD and ACS.

You can find the detailed process to how to connect Windows Azure AD and authenticate the user.
Follow the link 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/

Comment: This is just the standard ASP.NET / ACS scenario - it doesn't involve WAAD.